# Ruby on Rails - Display a view as a lightbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox, colorbox

How do I display a view (new.html.slim) as a lightbox in rails? 
When the user clicks on sign-up, the lightbox should come up as a login form.
I'm using colorbox rails, and the code gives me a blank lightbox (the code works for images)

```
= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_path, class: "btn-signup map-toggle", :data => { :colorbox => true }
```

Comment: you should google for load colorbox content via ajax.

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def create
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render layout: !request.xhr? }
    end
end

= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_path, class: "btn-signup map-toggle", :data => { :colorbox => true }, remote: true
```

I don't know about colorbox (we made our own light box with ajax support). If you'd like me to detail how we do this with our own setup, please comment & I'll post code!!

Comment: The above code fixed it too! Thanks a lot! But I'm curious to know your code.

Comment: Okay let me post it for you!